# Фигура на css3 как на картинке

Tags: css, css3

Всем привет. Подскажите, как добиться такого эффекта как на картинке на css3 - у меня получается овал..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#oval {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #e9337c;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval">пред.</div>
```

Comment: И что-то у меня есть сомнения, что префиксные варианты работают так, как ты ожидаешь. Они тебе точно нужны? Это ж совсем старьё: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем такие большие значения border-radius?

```css
#oval {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #e9337c;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval">пред.</div>
```

Comment: Центрировать однострочный текст при помощи padding-top - это не лучший способ.

Comment: @Qwertiy верно, лучше использовать высоту строки, но думаю суть вопроса была не в этом.

Comment: А я думаю, как бы от высоты избавиться. Просто 50% даст эллипс. А как бы круги получить?

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e9337c;
  border-radius: 50px / 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>пред.</div>
```

Как сделать круг без использования фиксированной горизонтальной составляющей, не знаю.